# How to change color of edge in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, colors, matlab-figure, edge-detection

I have a script which takes an image to and applies some edge detection methods such as canny, sobel and log to it. When I run the file, a figure is drawn where the edges are white.

Is there a way to change the color of the edges to a preferred color?

```
function cw1
  im0 = imread('lighthouse.png');
  im = rgb2gray(im0);
  im3 = edge(im,'canny');
  im4 = edge(im, 'sobel');
  im5 = edge(im, 'log');
  im2 = my_edge1(im);
  subplot(3,2,1), subimage(im); title ('Original'); axis off
  subplot(3,2,2), subimage(im2); title ('My Edge'); axis off
  subplot(3,2,3), subimage(im3); title ('Canny'); axis off
  subplot(3,2,4), subimage(im4); title ('Sobel'); axis off
  subplot(3,2,5), subimage(im5); title ('Log'); axis off
end
```

Comment: Closely-related/duplicate: [Contour detection in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5853116/52738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not exactly well-defined, but I'll try to help anyway. Here's a demonstration using green edges:

```
function q47394633
  im = rgb2gray(imread('peppers.png'));
  e = edge(im); % logical matrix, where "true" indicates an edge.
  g = reshape(uint8([0 255 0]),[1,1,3]) .* uint8(e); % Turn the above to RGB while making
  figure();                                          % only the green channel nonzero.
  subplot(3,1,1); imshow(e);    % Show white edges
  subplot(3,1,2); imshow(g);    % Show green edges
  subplot(3,1,3); imshow(im+g); % Show green edges on the image
end
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, This is what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Good. If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) to mark this problem resolved.

Comment: Here is code my  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5te8--APn_yV-zzlbAriXJUf1gZl3si/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Rajan See the line with `g = reshape(uint8([0 255 0]),[1,1,3]) .* uint8(e);`? Now instead of `g` put `g2...g5`, and instead of `e` put `im2...im5` then, if you want to plot the edges use `g2...g5`, if you want the edges on the grayscale image use `im+g2...g5`, and if you want the edges on the color image - use `im0+g2...g5`. Regarding your code, it should appear in your question, and not in a comment. This time I added it for you (to the question), but please make sure you add it right from the start.

Comment: does g2 to g5 and im2 to im5 needs to be repeated

Comment: @Rajan I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I think the answer is "_yes_".

Comment: @Rajan No, you put it in the wrong place, it must come after all of the definitions of `im...im5`, because they function as the `e = edge ...` in my code. Also, you shouldn't add answer code to your question.

Comment: I fixed the code and now works. I tried it for my own edge (Thresholding) but does not display properly

Comment: @Rajan I believe your original problem is solved, and I have no idea what "_does not display properly_" mean. If you have a follow-up issue, please ask a new question showing the current result and explaining the desired behavior. You may provide a link to this question for reference.